# Android handler remove send message not working

Tags: android, handler

Android handler remove previous send message from the handler message queue. *Remember* I don't want to use `removeCallbacks` (`Runnable` r);

Send broadcast intents
- To send the message

```
      Intent i = new Intent(my_action);  
      sendBroadcast(i);
```

- To cancel any previous message

```
Intent i = new Intent(my_action);  
i.putExtra("a","a"); 
sendBroadcast(i);

public class TestBroadCast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Handler h = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // Do my stuff
        }
    };
    Message msg = h.obtainMessage();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if ("a".equals(intent.getStringExtra("a"))){
            // Handle intent to cancel message
            msg.what = 1;
            h.removeMessages(1);
        } else {
            // Handle intent to do my stuff
            msg.what = 1;
            h.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 10000);
        }
    }
}
```

But after this `removeMessages` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reuse a `Message` I've tried that in the past and it doesn't work, you should obtain a new one.

Remove:

```
Message msg = h.obtainMessage();
```

Modify:

```
else { 
        // Handle intent to do my stuff 
        Message msg = h.obtainMessage();
        msg.what = 1;
        h.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 10000);
    }
```

You also should make your `Handler` static, I suspect that is the reason for your problems. The `BroadcastReceiver` may be short lives and be created and destroyed before your handler fires.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your handler to Application class, here's the reason why:

Your BroadcastReceiver creates multiple handler instances after getting broadcast each time, so Message.target assigned different Handler instance from h.obtainMessage(). Therefore, Handler.removeMessages() will be failed to remove message after checking Message.target.
Here's the related source code of how Messagequeue.removeMessages() and check target handler:

```
while (p != null && p.target == h && p.what == what
   && (object == null || p.obj == object)) {
   Message n = p.next;
   mMessages = n;
   p.recycleUnchecked();
   p = n;
}
```